# Can I use map / imap / imap_unordered with functions with no arguments?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Sometimes I need to use multiprocessing with functions with no arguments. I wish I could do something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f():  # no argument
    return 1

# TypeError: f() takes no arguments (1 given)
print Pool(2).map(f, range(10))
```

I could do `Process(target=f, args=())`, but I prefer the syntax of `map` / `imap` / `imap_unordered`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Would you be willing to redefine `f` to take one argument and ignore it?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: no, I'd rather avoid that

Comment: I have a feeling this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So, let's take a step back: what are you actually trying to do, for which you are trying to use this function?

Comment: The semantics of `map` imply that you're mapping a function *to a sequence of inputs*, so that's what you get. Whether you decide to ignore that argument, or create a wrapper function that's up to you.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: one example is to stress test a database or an API. I need to spawn N identical processes which will send requests repeatedly.

Comment: In that case, please edit your post to show a representative example of exactly what you're trying to do, so that we can give you an answer that is hopefully both meaningful as well as to your liking

Comment: @inspectorG4dget So do you have another way of doing this that's not an XY problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`map` function's first argument should be a function and it should accept one argument. It is mandatory because, the iterable passed as the second argument will be iterated and the values will be passed to the function one by one in each iteration.

So, your best bet is to redefine `f` to accept one argument and ignore it, or write a wrapper function with one argument, ignore the argument and return the return value of `f`, like this

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f():  # no argument
    return 1

def throw_away_function(_):
    return f()

print(Pool(2).map(throw_away_function, range(10)))
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

You cannot use `lamdba` functions with pools because they are not picklable.

Comment: it does not have to be a function accepting one argument only. you can use partial if you want to pass more arguments.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `pool.starmap()` instead of `.map()` like so:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f():  # no argument
    return 1

print Pool(2).starmap(f, [() for _ in range(10)])
```

`starmap` will pass all elements of the given iterables as arguments to `f`. The iterables should be empty in your case.

Comment: This can be rewritten as: `print(Pool(2).starmap(f, [[]] * 10))`.

Answer (score 3):

Is there anything wrong with using `Pool.apply_async`?

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    future_results = [pool.apply_async(f) for i in range(n)]
    results = [f.get() for f in future_results]
```

Comment: This throws an error (Python 2.7):  with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
AttributeError: __exit__

Answer (score 0):

For using the method pool, from library multiprocessing, you should provide an argument.
Thus, you should use another method like Process from multiprocessing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```